# Broken function due to multiple select declarations

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a DIV with content that's changed based on the selection made in a drop-down. I want to have multiple in one page but `select` is already declared.

How would I go about having this twice? It works when there's just one, as shown below.

```js
let select = document.querySelector("#menu");
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content>div");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.remove("showprev");
    if (options[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options[i].classList.add("showprev");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});
```

```css
.hideprev {
  display: none;
}

.showprev {
  display: block;
}

select {
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="menu">
    <option value="Not Selected" disabled selected>Make a selection</option>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">
  <div class="hideprev showprev">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>
```

But, when duplicated and another class set for each it doesn't work because select has already been declared so this breaks both.

```js
let select = document.querySelector("#menu");
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content>div");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.remove("showprev");
    if (options[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options[i].classList.add("showprev");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});

let select = document.querySelector("#menu1");
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content1>div");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.remove("showprev1");
    if (options[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options[i].classList.add("showprev1");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});
```

```css
.hideprev {
  display: none;
}

.showprev {
  display: block;
}

.hideprev1 {
  display: none;
}

.showprev1 {
  display: block;
}

select {
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: black;
  background: red;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.content {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content1 {
  min-height: 250px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border: solid red 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select id="menu">
    <option value="Not Selected" disabled selected>Make a selection</option>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content">
  <div class="hideprev showprev">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div class="January20 hideprev">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div class="February20 hideprev">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div class="March20 hideprev">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div class="April20 hideprev">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div class="May20 hideprev">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div class="June20 hideprev">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div class="July20 hideprev">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div class="August20 hideprev">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div class="September20 hideprev">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div class="October20 hideprev">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div class="November20 hideprev">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div class="December20 hideprev">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div class="January21 hideprev">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div class="February21 hideprev">Content from February 2021</div>

</div>

<br><br>

<select id="menu1">
    <option value="Not Selected" disabled selected>Make a selection</option>
  <optgroup label="2021">
    <option value="January21">January</option>
    <option value="February21">February</option>
    <optgroup label="2020">
      <option value="January20">January</option>
      <option value="February20">February</option>
      <option value="March20">March</option>
      <option value="April20">April</option>
      <option value="May20">May</option>
      <option value="June20">June</option>
      <option value="July20">July</option>
      <option value="August20">August</option>
      <option value="September20">September</option>
      <option value="October20">October</option>
      <option value="November20">November</option>
      <option value="December20">December</option>
</select>
<div class="content1">
  <div class="hideprev1 showprev1">You need to make a selection above first</div>
  <div class="January20 hideprev1">Content from January 2020</div>
  <div class="February20 hideprev1">Content from February 2020</div>
  <div class="March20 hideprev1">Content from March 2020</div>
  <div class="April20 hideprev1">Content from April 2020</div>
  <div class="May20 hideprev1">Content from May 2020</div>
  <div class="June20 hideprev1">Content from June 2020</div>
  <div class="July20 hideprev1">Content from July 2020</div>
  <div class="August20 hideprev1">Content from August 2020</div>
  <div class="September20 hideprev1">Content from September 2020</div>
  <div class="October20 hideprev1">Content from October 2020</div>
  <div class="November20 hideprev1">Content from November 2020</div>
  <div class="December20 hideprev1">Content from December 2020</div>
  <div class="January21 hideprev1">Content from January 2021</div>
  <div class="February21 hideprev1">Content from February 2021</div>
```

I've duplicated it and changed the class names but select and options have already been declared. How would I ensure that this can be duplicated for each class if more than one is to be shown on a page, would you loop them, change the function name for each, set different listeners?

I'm not sure what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it in a function and call that twice. Don't copy code to duplicate functionality.

Comment: I've updated my question with more context @Bergi

Comment: why there is multiple declarations of select are they different code?

Comment: The desired function is the same, run the second snippet to see @ProClasic

Answer (score 1):

You should add to all selects some common class, e.g. `js-select` and then add same listener to all of them.

```
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.js-select');
const onChange = function(options) { 
   /*...return your listener from here */
   return function(event) {
     if (options)...
   }
}

selects.forEach(function(select) {
  const options = select.querySelectorAll('option'); // get options 
  select.addEventListener('change', onChange(options));
})
```

Comment: Hey @Maryja Piaredryj, I've updated my question with full context, I don't understand your answer and can't make that fit with what I had.

Comment: @helpmeplease as I see in your snippet, you're doing `let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content1>div");` twice, you're selecting `oprions` belonging to only first select, not to the second one

Answer (score -1):

```
let select = document.querySelector("#menu");
let options = document.querySelectorAll(".content>div");

select.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.remove("showprev");
    if (options[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options[i].classList.add("showprev");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});

let select1 = document.querySelector("#menu1");
let options1 = document.querySelectorAll(".content1>div");

select1.addEventListener("change", function() {
// here do something once selected option is changed 

// example looping on a few div and comparing classname to select.value 
  for (let i = 0; i < options1.length; i++) {
    options1[i].classList.remove("showprev1");
    if (options1[i].classList.contains(this.value)) {
      options1[i].classList.add("showprev1");
    }
// end loop example     
  }
});
```

you are re-declaring the variables in your code.... `let` and `const` don't allow you to re-declare variables (but `var` does).

and you can simplify your code by making a function